# spring mvc (aop), can spring aspect or other way to get a method which intercepted where is it invoked?

Tags: spring, aop

```
//
public void testa(){
    testb();
    sayHello();
}
//
public void testb(){
    sayHello();
}
//
private void sayHello() {
}
```

My question is, when `@Aspect` use `@Around` intercept the 3 methods (`testa`, `testb`, `sayHello`). How can I know `sayHello()` is invoked by which method (a or b) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection to fetch stacktrace for method called. You probably need something like this :

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

Javadocs say :

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack, which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

Comment: thx for your advice.  i have think this way before, as the stackTrace was mix up by the spring aop proxy ,so i need iterator all the elements of the stack to find  my own method code. but as you say,this maybe the only way to handle my problem.